# How do you create a new Google Drive Service in C# using OAuth

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to write a simple command line application that will upload a file to Google Drive.  I'm following along with the steps provided here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-cs

The sample code they provide doesn't compile, specifically the line:

```
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                Authenticator = auth
            });
```

This returns the error:

"'Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initalizer' does not contain a definition for 'Authenticator'"

obviously the APIs have changed but I can't find the new way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off you are missing the autentication code.  Also the tutorial you are refering to uses an older version of the libary if you are using  apis.drive.v2 that wont work. This one works with the newer libarys:  My Tutorial [Google Drive api C#](http://daimto.com/google-drive-api-c/) (there is also a winform sample project)

But heres some Examples of how you can get it working:

```
UserCredential credential; 
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
          new ClientSecrets { ClientId = "YourClientId", ClientSecret = "YourClientSecret" },
          new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
            DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
          "user",
          CancellationToken.None,
          new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result; }
```

The code above will get you the User Credentials. It pops up a new browser window asking the user to autorise your app. [My Tutorial here](http://daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/)

```
BaseClientService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
 HttpClientInitializer = credential,
 ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
 });
```

The code above allow you to access the Drive Service.  See how we send it the credential that we got from the Oauth call?   Then to upload its a matter of calling service.files.insert

```
// File's metadata.
File body = new File();
body.Title = "NewDirectory2";
body.Description = "Test Directory";
body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = "root" } };
try
   {
   FilesResource.InsertRequest request = service.Files.Insert(body);
   request.Execute(); 
  }
 catch (Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
}
```

Comment: That was incredibly helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: What if I already have access_token and don't want this popup for user authorization? because I want to use it server to server to access user's google driver to save documents transparently.

Comment: How can I use second example that uses the DriveService with no credentials to access a publicly shared folder that I have the sharable link to?