# Google Drive REST Api download file by its fileId

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-api, google-drive-api

Hello guys I run into a problem. In my application  I am storing  fileId's of files which user selected before in GoogleDrive file picker. Also I am storing a local copy of that files in device. After each start I want to refresh local files, so I want to download them from drive. But it is not cleare for me, how should i do this. 
I saw [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads), but I can't understand where to get `driveService`, which used in this code

```
driveService.files().get(fileId)
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

I don't know what `driveService` is in this code. (Which class instance) and how do I get it 
Help me please, thank you.

P.S. 
Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should check the documentation under [resumable Media Downloads](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-download) it might give you some clues.

```
class CustomProgressListener implements MediaHttpDownloaderProgressListener {
  public void progressChanged(MediaHttpDownloader downloader) {
    switch (downloader.getDownloadState()) {
      case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
        System.out.println(downloader.getProgress());
        break;
      case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
        System.out.println("Download is complete!");
    }
  }
}

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/driveFile.jpg");

DriveFiles.Get request = drive.files().get(fileId);
request.getMediaHttpDownloader().setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener());
request.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
```

Comment: Maybe I can't understand something, but in this code "driveService" only renamed as "drive" and nothing else. But this is my greatest problem, I don't know what "drive" is in this code

Comment: this might help https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

Answer (score 0):

```
BaseClientService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
 HttpClientInitializer = credential,
 ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
 });
```

You should check this stack answer, maybe it will help you understand it:
[How do you create a new Google Drive Service in C# using OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569735/how-do-you-create-a-new-google-drive-service-in-c-sharp-using-oauth)